# Need basic AIOps implementation example for log monitoring in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, artificial-intelligence, devops

AIOps seems like a very interesting topic. I also watched AWS Summit presentation on this.

I have a logging nad monitoring solution where all system and application logs of all EC2 and EKS are forwarded cloudwatch log group.

To get a jump start on AIOps, how can I use AI to predict/preempt incidents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered cloudwatch already provides a fair amount of IOps already built in.

"Cloudwatch Anomaly Detection" - this seems to do the trick!

Very nice video on this available here - https://youtu.be/8umIX-pUy3k

Comment: This uses AI techniques to train using data and find out anomalies. But looks like it might not help in prevention or preemption.

Comment: Would anyone know of any cool example how AIOps could be used to "predict" and "preempt" incidents?